# Does Asmodeus have a 5e stat block?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I am trying to find a 5e stat block Asmodeus but I am beginning to think there isn't one. Does anybody know if there is a 5e Asmodeus stat block and where to find it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### There is none (yet)

As of April 29, 2021 there is no officially provided stat block from Wizards of the Coast. The closest are those for Zariel, Bel, and some of the other arch dukes and dukes.

Answer (score 8):

#### No.

[This DNDBeyond search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=asmodeus&f=monsters&c=monsters)  would yield an official Asmodeus stat block, if it existed.